# I want to send multiple choice data to the same column

Tags: php

Hy, I want to insert different data to the same column in the database. let see the Picture first. if the user can `check` the `New Product?` checkbox. then I want this can be stored in the `product_label` column of the database with a value of `new`. Now if someone clicks the `Product on Sale?` checkbox then I want to send the value `sale` to the database column `product_label`. and if the user cannot be checked the both of the checkboxes then I want to send `null` to the `product_label` column of the database.

[image]

Now here is the HTML code for that. I just show only the checkboxes from the HTML code because the rest of the code is too lengthy.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Sale">New Product?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="new_product" name="new_product" class="checkbox checkboxsize">
    </div>
 </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="Sale">Product On Sale?</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="sale" name="sale" class="checkbox checkboxsize">
        </div>
</div>
```

and this is PHP code for insertion.

```
    $new_product = $_POST['new_product'];
        $label = $_POST['sale']; 
        if($label==true)
            {
                 $label="sale";
            }
        else if($new_product==true){
                $new_product ="new";
        }
        else{

        }
$query = "INSERT INTO `products`(`product_title`, `product_img1`, `product_img2`, `product_img3`, `product_price`, `product_desc`, `product_keywords`,`product_size`, `product_color`,`product_label`) VALUES ('$product_category','$category','$title','$path1','$path2','$path3','$price','$description','$keywords','$product_size','$product_color','$label')";
```

Now here I am stuck with this code. I didn't know how to get and insert these value to the same column `product_label`

Comment: How do you want to handle it if they select both checkboxes?

Comment: Personally, I'd probably have two columns, `isNew` and `isSale` and have them be boolean or tinyint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a checkbox is not checked the name of the input doesn't exist in $_POST array, you have to use isset().

So try this :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['sale']))
{
    $label = "sale";
}
else if(isset($_POST['new_product'])) {
    $label = "new";
}
else{
    $label = '';
}
```

Comment: Based on this accepted answer, if they check both boxes, it will always have 'sale' as the label. Not sure if that is what you are wanting, but doesn't sound like it.

Answer (score 0):

I would create two columns in your table, isNew and isSale and set them both to boolean, false by default.

```
$isNew = isset($_POST['new_product']) ? 1 : 0;
$isSale = isset($_POST['sale']) ? 1 : 0;

INSERT INTO {table} ... (isNew,isSale) VALUES ($isNew,$isSale);
```

Comment: This may answer the question, but it would help if you could also provide a brief explanation of the solution.